# Identifying and eliminating contributions to the Eclipse 'footer' area

Tags: eclipse

My Eclipse installation has an unfortunate habit of accumulating 'contributions' in the lower part, below the editor, which apparently do nothing, but can't be removed or properly resized. Unless I'm aggresive about removing other, more controllable, parts it ends up on two rows, which is extremely annoying.

Even though it's on one row, I do get useless contributions, right in the middle, between 'Smart insert' and the calendar entry.

[Screenshot http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/56/eclipsefooter.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/56/eclipsefooter.png)

How can I identify and get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

I do have those as well, and the [Plug-in Spy](http://scratsh.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/eclipse-3-5-plug-in-spy-and-menus/) is not able to identify them.

Maybe (not tested) you could try and **reset your perspective**, to see if they are gone (and reconfigure your perspective from there)

[image]